# How can I trigger an action programmatically?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have this view

```
  App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'application',

    actions: {
      myAction: function() {
        //
      }
    }
  });
```

Suppose I want to trigger manually that action from another view method, such as didInsertElement, like:

```
  App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'application',

    actions: {

      sidebarShowHome: function() {
        this.set('sidebarIsHome', true);
        this.set('sidebarIsNotifications', false);
        this.set('sidebarIsArchive', false);
      },
    },

    didInsertElement: function() {
      this.actions.sidebarShowHome();
    }
  });
```

How could I do it? this.actions is undefined from within a view method.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [`TargetActionSupport`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TargetActionSupport.html) mixin along with [`this.triggerAction`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TargetActionSupport.html#method_triggerAction):

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend(Ember.TargetActionSupport, {
  templateName: 'application',
  actions: {
    myAction: function() {
      console.log('myAction');
    }
  },
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.triggerAction({
      action:'myAction',
      target: this
    });
  }
});
```

By default using `this.triggerAction()` without parameters will send the action to the controller, however if you need to target a different destination define the `target` option as shown in the example.

Working [demo](http://jsbin.com/OLELuta/2/edit).

Hope it helps.

Comment: @intuitivepixel Is there a way to pass an argument to the action?

Comment: @JonKoops, to really, to pass arguments you should use the context and the controller that can be passed along: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TargetActionSupport.html#method_triggerAction and grab from there your needed values/params etc.

Comment: Great answer intuitivepixel, how would you pass in a parameter to triggerAction if the action it was calling took in a parameter. For e.g myAction(param), then how can we pass a parameter when this action is invoked from triggerAction ?

Comment: @Parijat Kalia, seconding your question! 

Edit: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340963/passing-parameters-to-ember-triggeraction-which-calls-an-action-that-takes-param

Comment: @vanthome you should add your comment as an answer

Comment: @Karl but it will work if you extend Ember.ViewTargetActionSupport (not done by default).

Answer (score 15):

To call an action **in the same controller** you can use **`send`**.

```
this.send('nameOfAction', someParams);
```

To call an action **in the parent controller** from a component use **`sendAction`**.

```
this.sendAction('nameOfAction', someParams);
```

Answer (score 12):

The `triggerAction()` method only exists, if the view uses the `Ember.TargetActionSupport` mixin. If this is not the case, use `this.get('controller').send('action');` instead.

Comment: triggerAction() totally exists. You are reading the question incorrectly, this.get('controller').send('action') will call an action declared in the actions object within the controller, triggerAction() is used for triggering an action from within the same view which is what the question states.

Comment: triggerAction doesn't exist - if you're not using the Ember.TargetActionSupport mixin

Comment: `triggerAction` does exist, but it certainly makes more sense to use [`send`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_send).