# Passing parameters to Ember triggerAction which calls an action that takes parameters

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

In my EmberApp, I have a view, in which, upon the completion of an action, calls another 'view' action. This is a childView, and I essentially do this like this:

```
<button {{action "doSomething"  target="view"}}>DO something</button>
```

In the parent view,

```
Ember.View.extend({

   actions:{
       doSomething: function(){
            //perform tasks related to this view
            this.get('childViewName').triggerAction({action:"someAction", target:this.get('childViewName')}) 
       // invoke action that belongs to a child view
      }
```

});

The child view, as specified in http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ViewTargetActionSupport.html#method_triggerAction , passes in an Ember.TargetActionSupport mixin, and in its own actions, has the following:

```
Ember.ChildView.extend(Ember.ViewTargetActionSupport,{
   actions:{
       someAction:function(){
            console.log("some action called from the Parent view");  // executes fine
       }
     }
 });
});
```

As you can tell, this piece of code executes as it ought to. However, '**someAction**' **actually takes in a parameter (a model).** This model can be given to my Handlebars button expression quite easily by providing the '**this**' keyword as a parameter.

```
 <button {{action "doSomething" this target="view"}}>DO something</button>
```

It can also be retrieved in 'doSomething' acton by simply stating that doSomething takes in a parameter, like this:

```
doSomething(modelInstance){
// modelInstance parameter will map to this keyword as specified in the handlebars action 
}
```

The problem is, I don't know how to send this modelInstance or the 'this' keyword to my ChildView action through the triggerAction call. TriggerAction only takes in the 'action' keyword and the target parameter as mentioned in the docs.

Any idea/alternate solutions ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

actionContext will set the this of the action, so you can set the this of the action using it

```
doSomething: function(model){
   //perform tasks related to this view
   this.get('childViewName').triggerAction({action:"someAction", target:this.get('childViewName'), actionContext:model}) 
       // invoke action that belongs to a child view
}


someAction:function(){
   console.log(this);  // this would be the model from doSomething
}
```